# Phonegap FormData not being sent using CORS

Tags: javascript, cordova, cors

I have a phonegap app (currently using phonegap 3.5) and I set up a CORS request thus:

```
function createCORSRequest(method, url, asynchronous) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    //var n = currentTime.getTime();
    var n = 'nocache=' + generateRandomString(10);
    if (url.indexOf('?') == -1) {
        n = '?' + n;
    }
    else {
        n = '&' + n;
    }
    if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.open(method, url + n, asynchronous);
        //xhr.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
        //xhr.setRequestHeader('cache-control', 'no-cache');
    } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);
    } else {

        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;
    }
    return xhr;
}
```

I then create a request object:

```
var url = base_url + 'login.php';
var xhrLogin = createCORSRequest('POST', url, false);
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('loginemail','a@b.com');
formData.append('pwd','mypassword');
xhrLogin.send(formData);
```

On the server, I have the following PHP:

```
$postdata = '';

foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $postdata .= ' ' . $key . '=' . $value . ';';
}
if (strlen($postdata) == 0) {
    sendResponse(200, 'Error: No post data ' . $postdata, 'text/html');
    return;
}
```

When I run this code in a browser, straight off the disk (or from Brackets) it works OK no matter what my base_url variable is pointing to. If I run this via the phonegap server (either in a browser or on a device using the phonegap developer app) the form data is posted OK when I target my test server but on the production server it reports that no POST variables exist. In each case I view the network tab in chrome (F12) and verify that the username and password are being sent.

If I build the app and run on either Android or iOS it works fine on either server. It just appears to go awry running from phonegap server and when the url is pointing at the production server. (I also tried in IE too as the createCorsRequest code is slightly different for that, the same thing happens).

As you can see from the first block of code, I have tried the nocache tricks from other posts on this forum with similar errors but to no avail.

Test server is running php 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.3
Prod server is running php 5.4.20

Could the version of php be affecting this?

Update: I tried this from home and it sent data to both servers, it could be a proxy issue.

Update2: Running phonegap serve from a Mac seems to work OK (I was running it on a Linux box)

---

It would appear that this is down to the version, I had 3.5.0-0.21.14 installed at work and 3.5.0-0.20.4 at home. As the Mac worked at work I took my work laptop home and tested and it exhibited the same problems.

An interesting thing is that if I run the app from a Ripple Emulator, the CORS requests work fine as long as I disable Ripple's cross domain proxy.

Installing the earlier version at work has fixed the problem

```
$ npm install -g phonegap@3.5.0-0.20.4
```

Comment: What do you mean by a Phonegap server?It is not a server, it is a framework.
Please clarify the line below:
If I build the app and run on either Android or iOS it works fine on either server.

Comment: There is a server built in (run "phonegap serve" in project directory). The app is then served to the Phonegap Developer app. To clarify the other line, if I build the app and run it on a device it will send data to whichever server using cors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add the whitelist plugin for the Android build. This enabled the urls specified in config.xml